# "NOT IN" with HQL and Grails

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, grails, hql

The following query should select all organisations that are not in the `excludedOrgs`:

```
Organisation.findAll("from Organisation o where o not in elements(?)", 
    [excludedOrgs])
```

All I get is an org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException telling me: `expecting IDENT, found '?'`

I'm using Grails 1.3.6.

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 8):

both should work (as named and positional params are allowed)

```
Organisation.findAll("from Organisation o where o not in (?)", [excludedOrgs])

Organisation.findAll("from Organisation o where o not in (:excludedOrgs)", ["excludedOrgs":excludedOrgs])
```